# Excel with start thinks my parameter string is a file name

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, vba

I have just finished writing my first-ever VBA program which is invoked with the following instruction:

```
start excel "S:\stat\global\workgroup\BCDM\VBA\central_SDLC_doc_setup.xlsm" /e %1
```

This instruction is a `cmd` script file in which the value of %1 is the following:

```
"verbose=False|requester=S:\stat\global\macros\validation\wendy\v1.00\01_sdlc_docs|macro_name=wendy|macro_version=v1.00|macro_owner=rbaumann|macro_effective_start_date=2021-10-29"
```

I have the parameter interface functions set up in what appears to be the standard way:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCommandLine Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As LongLong
Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As LongLong) As LongLong
Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (MyDest As Any, MySource As Any, ByVal MySize As LongLong)

Function CmdToSTr(Cmd As LongLong) As String etc. etc.
```

The program seems to run perfectly, until the very end, where the following error message appears:

```
Sorry, we couldn’t find verbose=FaIse|requester=S:/stat/gIobal/macros/vaIidation/wendy/v1.00/01 _sdIc_docs|macro_name=wendy|macro_version=v1.001|macro_owner=rbaumann|macro_efective_start_date=2021-10-29.  Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
```

i.e., it had interpreted my parameter string as if it were a file name.  I poured through all of my VBA code trying to find what could possibly be the basis for that message, and could not find anything.  After my last VBA instruction in the program I included a MsgBox “I am done” instruction, which popped up on my next program invocation as expected, and then the above error message still followed.

It finally occurred to me that the problem was not in my VBA program code, but was in some sort of convention whereby any time Excel is invoked with a parameter string, it always treats the parameter string as being the name of a file and tries to open it.

Is this indeed the case?  If so, how can I override such behavior so that after my VBA code has completed execution nothing more happens?

Thank you.

Comment: `verbose=FaIse` in the error message contains a capital `i`, as does `gIobal` and a bunch more.

Comment: You might need to escape the pipe `|` character

Comment: I don't think Excel supports user parameters. You could pass the parameter as an environment variable and get it using the [Environ function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function).

Comment: Hi @David and harrymc,
Thanks for your quick responses, I appreciate them.   
Of note, the presence of the "I" characters and other anomalies in the error message as posted here is because Excel always displays that message in a picture, not as text, so I captured a screen shot of the picture and put it through an OCR program to convert it to text.  Some characters were not accurately recognized.  But in the original picture that was displayed as the error message, the message was correct.

Comment: Excel definitely supports user parameters. There’s much out on the web about it. That part of my program is working fine, it correctly grabs the parameter string that I pass it and then using a VBA Regex object with field capture codes defined around parameter value text strings it parses the values from the parameter string, which are then used in the rest of the program. My only problem is the above error message always popping up after my program finishes. Regarding user parameters, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757827/excel-64-bit-command-line-vba-code. Best, fireblood.

Answer (score 0):

for reasons I don't fully understand the problem stopped occurring.  My VBA code now runs from start to finish and there is no message from Excel afterwards about being able to find my parameter string which it has treated as a file name.  I've compared several successive versions of my Excel workbook and the VBA code within and have not been able to identify anything that would explain why the above-noted error message is no longer popping up at the end of every execution of the program.  Thanks again to @david and harrymc for providing early thoughts about the possible causes of the problem.